# Do I understand De Broglie–Bohm theory correctly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bohmian-mechanics

In the interpretation of quantum mechanics developed by David Bohm (De Broglie–Bohm theory), the wave function is considered as a real-life physical field that evolves according to the Schrödinger equation. However, apart from the universal wave function, there are also classical particles with classical trajectories. The whole collection of classical particles is in some configuration, defined as a point in the configuration space. The evolution of the entire configuration of particles depends on the wave function and on the initial state of the configuration (which is unknown to the observer).

That is, if you set two different initial conditions for two different configurations (two different "universes"), then the evolution of these two configurations will be different? If not, what determines how the entire configuration will evolve?